# Get file path from Tkinter filedialog not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, tkinter, openfiledialog

Working on a project where I have a function that shows an open file dialog and prints out the path to the selected file.

My code looks like this:

```py
import tkinter
import customtkinter

def openFile(self):
        filePath = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=startingDir, title="Open File", filetypes=(("Open a .txt file", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))
        if filePath == '':
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "You didn't select a file.")
        else:
            print(filePath)
```

However, I received this error from Visual Studio Code:

```
Argument of type "IO[Incomplete] | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "file" of type "_OpenFile" in function "open"
```

And this one from Python itself:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\benri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 377, in clicked
    self.command()
  File "C:\Users\benri\OneDrive\Desktop\My Files\Apps and Programs\Windows Programs\Python\TexType\editFile.py", line 51, in openFile
    mainFile = open(filePath, "r")
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper
```

---

#### UPDATE:

If I use the syntax `mainFile = open(str(filePath), "r")`, Python gives me the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PY_VAR0'

suggesting that this method of using `str()` results in a variable with invalid contents.

Comment: The line causing the exception does not exist in the posted code.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`askopenfile` returns a file *handle*, not a file *name*. Whatever file you pick is automatically opened and the handle is returned.

You can't pass a file handle to `open`. If you want the file *name*, use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`. Or, just use the already open file that `askopenfile` returns.

Comment: I don't think that worked! After getting the 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PY_VAR0'' error, I investigated the contents of the variable and found that it contained the value 'PY_VARO'.  Don't know what this means, do you? Thanks!

Comment: @BentheCoder: that is the internal name of a Tkinter variable.